# Count number of times each unique element appears in a list

Tags: r, list, count, unique

How do you count how many times each unique element appears in a list?

```
example_list <- list(
  c(1,1),
  c(1,2),
  c(1,1),
  c(1,2,3),
  c(1,1),
  c(1,2,3)
)
```

Edit: The unique elements are the vectors not the numbers inside the vectors

Comment: what do you count as an element, `1` or `c(1, 1)`? please show your expected output

Comment: expected output would be  c(3,1,2) corresponding to (1,1), (1,2) and (1,2,3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is the count of similar elements, one option is `paste` the elements in the `list` by looping over the `list` with `sapply` to create a `vector`, and get the frequency count with `table`

```
table(sapply(example_list, paste, collapse=' '))

#  1 1   1 2 1 2 3 
#    3     1     2
```

---

Or another option is to convert to a wide dataset from the `list` and use `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(col1 = example_list) %>% 
   unnest_wider(col1) %>% 
   count(across(everything()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Elements at indices 1, 2, and 4 are unique and appear 3, 1, and 2 times respectively

```
table(match(example_list, example_list))

# 1 2 4 
# 3 1 2
```